SharePoint Online List not respecting Formatting
We have a SharePoint online tenant with several subsites. Each subsite contains several lists and libraries. Suddenly, last week, we noticed a few oddities among some (not all) of our lists. They stopped displaying all entries (I can scroll through a list and after letter G it's blank but if I sort the list in descending order I'll see the remaining items until it's blank again). Further, these impacted lists have stopped respecting our formatting (even though the formatting is still showing when I click on formatting).
This is not affecting our entire tenant, only a couple of the lists within a couple of the pages.  Microsoft claims it's an issue with the data so I rebuilt the list from an export of the problem list. Interestingly, the rebuilt list now displays all entries but it still doesn't respect the formatting.
Other lists on other SP subsites are fine, they display all items and still format as programmed.
Has this been an issue for anyone else?  Any ideas?
